# making self-modifying code easier

Tags: python, self-modifying

I made a self modifying code that runs on python 2.7 and the code is a bit big and I was wondering if there was a way to make the code a bit easier, I've thought about it and I didn't find any answer... I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand, but anyway, here's the code

```
import sys
x = ['num = 0\n', 'from threading import *\n', 'import sys\n', 'def change(b, line=1):\n', '\tline -= 1\n', '\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n', '\tg = f.readlines()\n', '\tlines = []\n', '\tfor i in g:\n', '\t\tlines.append(i)\n', '\tlines[line] = b+"\\n"\n', "\tf = open(sys.argv[0], 'w')\n", '\tfor each in lines:\n', '\t\tf.write(each)\n', '\tf.close()\n', '\t\n', 'def addline(b):\n', '\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n', '\tg = f.readlines()\n', '\tlines = []\n', '\tfor i in g:\n', '\t\tlines.append(i)\n', '\tlines.append("\\n"+b)\n', "\tf = open(sys.argv[0], 'w')\n", '\tfor each in lines:\n', '\t\tf.write(each)\n', '\tf.close()\n', '\t\n', 'def delline(b = 10):\n', '\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n', '\tg = f.readlines()\n', '\tlines = []\n', '\tfor i in g:\n', '\t\tlines.append(i)\n', '\tleng = len(lines) - b\n', '\tlines = lines[:leng]\n', "\tf = open(sys.argv[0], 'w')\n", '\tfor each in lines:\n', '\t\tf.write(each)\n', '\tf.close()\n', '\t\t\n', 'def showfile():\n', '\tcheck = num\n', '\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n', '\tg = f.readlines()\n', '\twhile num != check + 1:\n', '\t\tfor i in g:\n', '\t\t\tprint i\n', '\t\n', '\t\n', 'if num == 0:\n', '\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n', '\tf = open("values.py", \'w\')\n', '\twriter = [\'linestowrite1 = [\\\'import os\\\\n\\\', \\\'from time import *\\\\n\\\',\\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("hello...")\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(2)\\\\n\\\', \\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("I am a program that is able to evolve by itself")\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(4)\\\\n\\\', \\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("everytime someone opens me, I evolve")\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(2)\\\\n\\\', \\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\',\\\'change("num = 2")\\\\n\\\' \\\'raw_input("press ENTER to exit")\\\\n\\\']\\n\', \'linestowrite2 = [\\\'from time import *\\\\n\\\', \\\'f = open(sys.argv[0])\\\\n\\\', \\\'g = f.readlines()\\\\n\\\', \\\'leng = len(g)\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(1)\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("CURRENT LENGTH : "+str(leng))\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(2)\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("Extending length to : "+str(leng+20))\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(3)\\\\n\\\', \\\'change("num = 5")\\\\n\\\', \\\'\\\\t\\\']\']\n', '\tfor i in writer:\n', '\t\tf.write(i)\n', '\tf.close()\n', '\timport values\n', '\ttowrite = values.linestowrite1\n', '\tfor i in towrite:\n', '\t\taddline(i)\n', '\tchange("num = 1")\n', '\tnum += 1\n', 'elif num == 2:\n', '\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n', '\tdelline(26)\n', '\tchange("num = 3")\n', '\tnum += 1\n', '\thorse69\n', 'elif num == 3:\n', '\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n', '\timport values\n', '\ttowrite = values.linestowrite2\n', '\tfor i in towrite:\n', '\t\taddline(i)\n', '\tchange("num = 4")\n', '\tnum += 1\n', 'elif num == 5:\n', '\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n', '\tdelline(21)\n', '\tchange("num = 6")\n', '\tnum += 1\n', '\thorse69\n', 'elif num == 6:\n', '\tprint("EVOLUTION COMPLETE")\n', '\traw_input()\n']
f = open(sys.argv[0], 'w')
for i in x:
    f.write(i)
f.close()
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Self-modifying code is not a standard idiom in Python.

Comment: While this is a cool idea, SO is not the place to ask for general coding advice, please make the question more specific. Though I do recommend reading up on a few things first: [self-modifying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) and [optimization of state dependent loops.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code#Optimizing_a_state-dependent_loop) There is a lot more on this topic that you should read before posting here.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?  Also you could simplify 3,4,5,6 lines as : `with open(sys.argv[0], 'w') as f : f.write(''.join(x))`

Comment: basically , I was interested in Self-modifying code but I know that python wouldn't be the language to normally use, but It made me interested in studying self-modifying code especially in python, and I think my code right here is a bit messy so I was asking if there was a way to make it neater, because a HUGE list is a bit annoying.

Comment: If you're interested only in getting different output each time you run your program, you can do it without modifying the source at all. You could instead keep track of how many times the program has executed, using a serialization module such as `pickle` or `json` or `shelve`, and have a big if-elif block that produces output based on that number. But I'm guessing that defeats the purpose of your experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a list, just use a string:

```
import sys

newcode = 'num = 0\nfrom threading import *\nimport sys\ndef change(b, line=1):\n\tline -= 1\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n\tg = f.readlines()\n\tlines = []\n\tfor i in g:\n\t\tlines.append(i)\n\tlines[line] = b+"\\n"\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0], \'w\')\n\tfor each in lines:\n\t\tf.write(each)\n\tf.close()\n\t\ndef addline(b):\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n\tg = f.readlines()\n\tlines = []\n\tfor i in g:\n\t\tlines.append(i)\n\tlines.append("\\n"+b)\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0], \'w\')\n\tfor each in lines:\n\t\tf.write(each)\n\tf.close()\n\t\ndef delline(b = 10):\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n\tg = f.readlines()\n\tlines = []\n\tfor i in g:\n\t\tlines.append(i)\n\tleng = len(lines) - b\n\tlines = lines[:leng]\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0], \'w\')\n\tfor each in lines:\n\t\tf.write(each)\n\tf.close()\n\t\t\ndef showfile():\n\tcheck = num\n\tf = open(sys.argv[0])\n\tg = f.readlines()\n\twhile num != check + 1:\n\t\tfor i in g:\n\t\t\tprint i\n\t\n\t\nif num == 0:\n\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n\tf = open("values.py", \'w\')\n\twriter = [\'linestowrite1 = [\\\'import os\\\\n\\\', \\\'from time import *\\\\n\\\',\\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("hello...")\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(2)\\\\n\\\', \\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("I am a program that is able to evolve by itself")\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(4)\\\\n\\\', \\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("everytime someone opens me, I evolve")\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(2)\\\\n\\\', \\\'os.system("cls")\\\\n\\\',\\\'change("num = 2")\\\\n\\\' \\\'raw_input("press ENTER to exit")\\\\n\\\']\\n\', \'linestowrite2 = [\\\'from time import *\\\\n\\\', \\\'f = open(sys.argv[0])\\\\n\\\', \\\'g = f.readlines()\\\\n\\\', \\\'leng = len(g)\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(1)\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("CURRENT LENGTH : "+str(leng))\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(2)\\\\n\\\', \\\'print("Extending length to : "+str(leng+20))\\\\n\\\', \\\'sleep(3)\\\\n\\\', \\\'change("num = 5")\\\\n\\\', \\\'\\\\t\\\']\']\n\tfor i in writer:\n\t\tf.write(i)\n\tf.close()\n\timport values\n\ttowrite = values.linestowrite1\n\tfor i in towrite:\n\t\taddline(i)\n\tchange("num = 1")\n\tnum += 1\nelif num == 2:\n\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n\tdelline(26)\n\tchange("num = 3")\n\tnum += 1\n\thorse69\nelif num == 3:\n\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n\timport values\n\ttowrite = values.linestowrite2\n\tfor i in towrite:\n\t\taddline(i)\n\tchange("num = 4")\n\tnum += 1\nelif num == 5:\n\tThread(target=showfile).start()\n\tdelline(21)\n\tchange("num = 6")\n\tnum += 1\n\thorse69\nelif num == 6:\n\tprint("EVOLUTION COMPLETE")\n\traw_input()\n'

with open(sys.argv[0], 'w') as f:
    f.write(newcode)
```

Applying the same principle to the inner code might help make it shorter.

Comment: did not think about that, it does make it neater and better to look at, thank you.